# Can I assume that Task scheduler service will always be running on windows machine?

Tags: windows, services, windows-task-scheduler

The requirement is to run an executable periodically in windows. So I assumed it will be better to do it by creating a task in task scheduler.

But I am afraid for any reason will the task scheduler service be disabled by default in any of the windows installations.

The ultimate question is, for periodically running an application shall I resort to task scheduler, if so what are the pros and cons of doing that ?

**PS**

The application is expected to be distributed as MSI

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/40848/is-the-task-scheduler-in-windows-xp-reliable-enough-to-be-trusted-with-important

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/722678/2825347